# Three monitors on two video cards (NVIDIA and RADEON)

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, radeon

I have the following settings on my PC:

- OpenSuse Leap  42.1
- Geforce GT 430 (with two monitors: DVI-I-1-1 and VGA-1-2)
- And a third monitor connected to the onboard video card (a Radeon 3000).

In the BIOS I set the option to boot to VGA-Onboard and I'm currently running three monitors simultaneously correctly. Really the operation is not optimal because when I move a window the image is cut, I think it must be because the GPU is not using the NVIDIA driver.

Here is my xrandr output, lspci and lshw (my xorg.conf is empty).

```
  @linux-yyga:~> sudo /usr/sbin/lshw -c display
root's password:
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS780L [Radeon 3000]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fdff0000-fdffffff memory:fde00000-fdefffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 430]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:de000000-dfffffff ioport:df00(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff


@linux-yyga:~> /sbin/lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A2
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780L [Radeon 3000] [1002:9616]
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
--
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 430] [10de:0de1] (rev a1)
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia

@linux-yyga:~> xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5440 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        60.0  
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 connected 1920x1080+3520+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   1920x1080_60.00   60.0* 
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-2 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x800       74.9     59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
  1024x768 (0x65)   65.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x66)   40.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x67)   36.0MHz
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x512)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
  1440x900 (0x6c)  106.5MHz
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock   55.9KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock   59.9Hz
  1280x800 (0x6e)   83.5MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock   49.7KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock   59.8Hz
  640x480 (0x78)   25.2MHz
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   60.0Hz
```

To try to solve this I installed the NVIDIA driver from YAST (computeG04) and only supports the monitor connected to the Radeon and xrandr does not detect GPU interfaces.

At the moment I uninstalled the NVIDIA driver and I am using the nouveau driver.

What can I do to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "when I move a window the image is cut"?  How to avoid that seems to be what you are asking, but I don't know exactly what you mean.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminStaton, thank for your help. I'll try to be clearer:  Basically what happens is that by not using the driver nvidia video performance is not optimal. For instance: I am getting is that rendering actions is slow, for example, opening a new tab in Chrome.